# Как внедрить или передать JPARepository в контроллер?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Есть класс "Parser", который берёт загруженный файл через get запрос и заносит данные в базу данных H2. Если использовать его в классе со SpringApplication.run, создав бин "CommandLineRunner demo(Repository repo)", то класс обрабатывает файл.
При попытке воспользоваться тем же классом "Parser" в классе-контроллере, не удается передать репозиторий.
Пробовал ставить @Autowired на переменную репозитория в классе "Parser", внедрял репозиторий в метод контроллера. Не получается, переменная с репозиторием null и всё.

Parser.java

```
@Component
public class Parser {
    Customer data;
    Visit visit;
    Cart cart;
    Pay pay;

    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    InetAddress ip;
    URL url;

    CartRepo cartRepo;
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;
    PayRepo payRepo;
    VisitRepo visitRepo;

    public void parsing(File logs){код обработки}
```

Controller.java

```
//метод обработки файла
public String parseFile(Model model,
                            Parser parser,
                            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                //Получение файла UploadFile
                parser.parsing(UploadFile);
                return "reports/list_of_reports.html";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //обработка исключений
                return "error.html";
            }
```

[Git](https://github.com/zdezak/Logs-to-Reports). В ветке main, работающий вариант класса, в ветке dev ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы передаете `Parser` параметром вместе с моделью и `RequestParam`-ом. Откуда форма, в которой вы вызываете метод `POST` знает про ваш парсер? Может, его нужно инжектить в том же контроллере, но выше?

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

private final Parser parser;

@Autowired
public IndexController(Parser parser) {
    this.parser = parser;
}

@GetMapping("/")
public String index(){
    return "index.html";
}
@PostMapping("/")
public String parseFile(Model model,
                        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            File UploadFile = new File("upload/logs.txt");
            BufferedOutputStream stream =
                    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(UploadFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            parser.parsing(UploadFile);
            return "reports/list_of_reports.html";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            model.addAttribute("message","Вам не удалось загрузить " + file.getName() + " => "+e.getMessage());
            return "error.html";
        }
    } else {
        model.addAttribute("message","Вам не удалось загрузить " + file.getName() + " потом что файл пустой.");
        return "error.html";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Даже не думал, что у контроллера можно сделать свой конструктор. Сделал конструктор, в который spring сам мне загрузил репозитории, а внутри уже создал объект нужного класса.

Comment: Ну а как иначе можно сконструировать бин?